# How to reverse proxy a docker image at domain root and another image at a subdomain with swag?

Tags: docker, nginx, lets-encrypt

I'm using "linuxserver"'s [swag](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/swag) image to reverse-proxy my docker-compose images. I want to serve one of my images as my domain root and the other one as a subdomain (*e.g. **root-image** @ mysite.com and **subdomain-image** @ staging.mysite.com*). Here are the steps I went through:

1. redirected my domain and subdomain names to my server in Cloudflare (pinging them shows my server's IP and this is step OK! )
2. Configured Cloudflare DNS config for swag (this working OK!)
3. Configured docker-compose file:

```
  swag:
    image: linuxserver/swag:version-1.14.0
    container_name: swag
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - URL=mysite.com
      - SUBDOMAINS=www,staging
      - VALIDATION=dns
      - DNSPLUGIN=cloudflare #optional
      - EMAIL=me@mail.com #optional
      - ONLY_SUBDOMAINS=false #optional
      - STAGING=false #optional
    volumes:
      - /docker-confs/swag/config:/config
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80 #optional
    restart: unless-stopped
  root-image:
    image: ghcr.io/me/root-image
    container_name: root-image
    restart: unless-stopped
  subdomain-image:
    image: ghcr.io/me/subdomain-image
    container_name: subdomain-image
    restart: unless-stopped
```

4. Defined a proxy conf for my root-image (at swag/config/nginx/proxy-confs/root-image.subfolder.conf)

```
location / {
    include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
    set $upstream_app root-image;
    set $upstream_port 3000;
    set $upstream_proto http;
    proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;
}
```

5. Commented out the nginx's default `location / {}` block (at swag/config/nginx/site-confs/default)
6. Defined a proxy conf for my subdomain-image (at swag/config/nginx/proxy-confs/subdomain-image.subdomain.conf)

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name staging.*;
    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    
    location / {
        include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
        resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
        set $upstream_app subdomain-image;
        set $upstream_port 443;
        set $upstream_proto https;
        proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;

    }
}
```

Both images expose port 3000. Now my root image is working fine (OK!), but I'm getting 502 error for my subdomain image. I checked the nginx error log, but it doesn't show anything meaningful for me:

```
*35 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx, server: staging.*, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "https://xxx.xxx.xxx:443/favicon.ico", host: "staging.mysite.com", referrer: "https://staging.mysite.com"
```

Docker logs for all the 3 containers are also fine (without showing any warnings or errors).

Which step I'm going wrong or is there anything I missed? Thanks for helping